# PHP объединить элементы многомерного массива по одинаковому значению

Tags: php, массивы, объединение

Исходный массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [artikul] => 822116
            [need_add] => 1
            [can_add] => 1
            [sklad] => Коледино
            [product_id] => 36162
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [artikul] => 26154
            [need_add] => 2
            [can_add] => 2
            [sklad] => Коледино
            [product_id] => 31388
            [quantity] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [artikul] => 112702
            [need_add] => 6
            [can_add] => 6
            [sklad] => Внуково
            [product_id] => 112702
            [quantity] => 6
        )

)
```

В результате объединить по названию склада

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array (
        
        [0] => Array
        (
            [artikul] => 822116
            [need_add] => 1
            [can_add] => 1
            [sklad] => Коледино
            [product_id] => 36162
            [quantity] => 1
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [artikul] => 26154
            [need_add] => 2
            [can_add] => 2
            [sklad] => Коледино
            [product_id] => 31388
            [quantity] => 2
        )
    )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [artikul] => 112702
            [need_add] => 6
            [can_add] => 6
            [sklad] => Внуково
            [product_id] => 112702
            [quantity] => 6
        )

)
```

Помогите!

Comment: Перепутал ресурс с фрилансом?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62594363/split-the-array-in-to-sub-arrays-based-on-array-key-value

```
$key = 'sklad';
$return = array();
foreach($array as $v) {
     $return[$v[$key]][] = $v;
}
print_r(array_values($return));
```